# Blocking Directories with .htaccess

Tags: css, .htaccess, block

I am trying to figure this out.

Lets say we have `http://domain.com/css` and that needs to be blocked. I used `Deny from All` in the htaccess, but then the user cannot see any styling on the page or website. I am stumped on what to do.

Comment: Need more information about what should and should not be blocked.

Comment: The directory /css/ or other assets should be blocked, but files such as style.css are still viewable. The issue with deny all is that it blocks the directory, but the website then has to css styling.

Comment: Do you have access to the server or is this shared hosting? You should never use .htaccess if you can avoid it, it has to search every parent directory to see if its overridden anywhere, so it's very inefficient.

Comment: Its shared but im moving to a vps soon. I figured it out. It was `Options All -Indexes`

Comment: @RTWNick, put that in an answer and mark it accepted For Posterity's Sake™.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was `Options All -Indexes`. That allowed the css to be seen and blocks directories.